# How to set cookie in my custom authentication view( django-rest-framework-simplejwt)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

After login `access` and `refresh` token seted in httponly cookie.So I create `CustomAuthentication`(Inherit from `JWTAuthentication`) view to get the httponly cookie.If access token invalid at that time `InvalidToken` error except(see my below code) then generate new access token by using refresh token.

**Question 1 :** How to set this access token in cookie?.Here I use `Response()` but it not work because `CustomAuthentication` view return user and token instead of response.

**Question 2 :**
Any other recommended way to generate new access token by using refresh token and set in cookie?

Sorry for my English..

**authenticate.py:**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken
from django.conf import settings
import requests
import json
from datetime import timedelta
from .utility import set_browser_cookie
from rest_framework.response import Response

def set_browser_cookie(response,key,value):
    response.set_cookie(
                       key = key, 
                       value = value,
                    #    expires = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
                       secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                       httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                       samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
                       )

  

class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)        
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None
        
        try:
            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        except InvalidToken:
            refresh = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH'])
            
            if refresh is None:
                return None
                                      
            protocol = 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
            url = f'{protocol}://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/api/token/refresh/'
            data = {"refresh": refresh}
            resp = requests.post(
                url, 
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
                )
            result = resp.json()
            new_access_token = result['access']
            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(new_access_token)
            
            response = Response()
            set_browser_cookie(response,settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'],new_access_token)
            
            print("new_tokennnnnnnnn",new_access_token)

        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

**Settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'authentication.authenticate.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**Advance thanks..**